# Facebook like button not showing like count [firefox]

Tags: facebook, firefox, facebook-like

I have a facebook like button in my blog using html5 but it doesn't display the count for visitors who didn't like. When someone hits the button, it displays 1 like (even though I tested with multiple facebook users liking it. (the like works, and it does appear on facebook.com)

tested in 3 different browsers.

this is the code I used:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div style="float: left;margin-left: 40px;" class="fb-like"  data-href="http://www.xxxxxx.com/?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>"  data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="true" data-font="segoe ui"></div>
```

EDIT: I think the problem is with firefox. when i like the page from firefox - doesn't show in other browsers. when i like from chrome or safari - shows in all except firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but what I figured out is, its because of caching of FB as when I like anything from Firefox then at the same time it dosent shows the count, but next day you will see all the shares and like. Am on wordpress.